# Errors running spring boot app in NetBeans

Tags: spring-boot, netbeans, hikaricp

I'm new to Spring Boot. After following a tutorial the idea was to develop a simple application in order to understand how Spring Boot apps work. After running the app apparently the result is successfull because it shows a sign indicating "Build Success", however there are some errors in the output.

While trying to run from NetBeans a SpringBoot app first i get this message about Hikari which i don't know what it is:

2023-04-02T20:12:34.420-03:00 ERROR 89692 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

Then follows this SQL exception:

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]

Answer (score 0):

[Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) is a JDBC [connection pool](https://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool). The exception says that Hikari cannot connect to your database because your credentials are wrong. Either you provided the wrong password for the database user "admin" or the user does not exist in your database.